# Customized command line parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, shell, command-line, arguments

I'm writing a shell for a project of mine, which by design parses commands that looks like this:

COMMAND_NAME ARG1="Long Value" ARG2=123 ARG3=me@me.com

My problem is that Python's command line parsing libraries (getopt and optparse) forces me to use '-' or '--' in front of the arguments. This behavior doesn't match my requirements.

Any ideas how can this be solved? Any existing library for this?

Comment: That white space in "Long Value" might give you additional trouble. I am not sure optparse (or other libraries) can handle this.

Comment: @Ralph: optparse handles "Long Value" just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could split them up with shlex.split(), which can handle the quoted values you have, and pretty easily parse this with a very simple regular expression. Or, you can just use regular expressions for both splitting and parsing. Or simply use split().

```
args = {}
for arg in shlex.split(cmdln_args):
    key, value = arg.split('=', 1)
    args[key] = value
```

Comment: In python 2.5 and above, you can also do: key, _, value= arg.partition('=')

Comment: args = dict(arg.split('=', 1) for arg in shlex.split(cmdln_args))

Answer (score 9):

1. Try to follow "[Standards for Command Line Interfaces](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces)"
2. Convert your arguments (as Thomas suggested) to OptionParser format.

   ```
   parser.parse_args(["--"+p if "=" in p else p for p in sys.argv[1:]])
   ```

If command-line arguments are not in sys.argv or a similar list but in a string then (as ironfroggy suggested) use `shlex.split()`.

```
parser.parse_args(["--"+p if "=" in p else p for p in shlex.split(argsline)])
```

Answer (score 2):

A small pythonic variation on Ironforggy's shlex answer:

```
args = dict( arg.split('=', 1) for arg in shlex.split(cmdln_args) )
```

oops... - corrected.

thanks,  J.F. Sebastian 
 (got to remember those single argument generator expressions).

Answer (score 1):

What about optmatch (http://www.coderazzi.net/python/optmatch/index.htm)? Is not standard, but takes a different approach to options parsing, and it supports any prefix:

OptionMatcher.setMode(optionPrefix='-')

Comment: @rafalotufo, I think your proposed edit to this question should have been a comment -- pointing out that a proposed solution won't work is changing the meaning of an answer pretty drastically. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without fairly intensive surgery on optparse or getopt, I don't believe you can sensibly make them parse your format. You can easily parse your own format, though, or translate it into something optparse could handle:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("--ARG1", dest="arg1", help="....")
parser.add_option(...)
...
newargs = sys.argv[:1]
for idx, arg in enumerate(sys.argv[1:])
    parts = arg.split('=', 1)
    if len(parts) < 2:
        # End of options, don't translate the rest. 
        newargs.extend(sys.argv[idx+1:])
        break
    argname, argvalue = parts
    newargs.extend(["--%s" % argname, argvalue])

parser.parse_args(newargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party... but [PEP 389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/) allows for this and much more.

Here's a little nice library should your version of Python need it code.google.com/p/argparse

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in a little Python module I wrote to make handling of command line arguments even easier (open source and free to use) - http://freshmeat.net/projects/commando